# Unable to login to SharePoint

Tags: configuration, sharepoint-2007

I had installed SharePoint 2007,with basic option on Windows Server 2003 standard edition. The installation was successful, after which IE opened up with a login dialog. I tried passing my administrator username and password, but still couldn't login.

I am completely new to Sharepoint, please help me to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got this resolved. So let me once more precisely explain the problem. After successful installation of sharepoint 2007 with basic option, the default browser( in my case IE) came up with the following URL http://MACHINE_NAME:14530/default.aspx (This URL points to Sharepoint Central Administration Page). A login dialog which kept popping up even after providing the administrator credentials. After some Googling, I came up with the following solution

Following steps were executed to get things on track. (I am using IE6. All these steps were executed on the same PC where SharePoint was installed)
1.Open IE, go to Tools - Internet Options

2.Add the Central Administration Page URL to "Trusted Sites".
  A) Click "Security" tab, select "Trusted Sites" icons with a green tick mark.
  B) Click "Sites" button. A window with the title "Trusted Sites" will open up.
  C) Uncheck "Require server verification(https:) for all sites in this zone"
  D) Paste the "Central Administration Page" URL to "Add this Web Site to the zone:"
  E) Click "Add"
  F) Click Close.

3.Configure "Custom level" for "Trusted Sites".
  A) Select "Trusted Sites" icon in "Security" tab.
  B) Click "Custom level" button.
  C) "Security Settings" window should open up.
  D) In settings list go to category "User Authentication"->Logon.
  E) Select "Automatic logon with current username and password".
  F) Click "OK". (Also click OK in the "Internet Options" window)

4.Now Restart IE and navigate to Sharepoint Central Administration Page. Now you shouldn't see any login window popping up.

Comment: Please let me know if there's any other better approach than the one posted by me.